# Measurement of indipendent variables for binary logistic regression

Tags: measurement

I want to run a binary logistic regression to understanding (modeling) factors affecting nest-site selection in a bird species..I measured 32 presence points and 64 absence points.

Instead of measuring random points as absence points, I measured points where I guessed the bird could build a nest. Is this measurement method correct?

Comment: Can you describe your sampling process a bit more for the sites with nests?

Comment: The variables I measured are not Environmental like soil types or vegetation types. I measured Nest detection chance, Nest height from ground, Nest to ceiling height and more

Comment: I think if you were to sample sites where birds could nest, and some of them turned out to have nests, that would be OK. Walk me through your process of finding sites with nests.

Comment: Actually sites with nests are exact places that nests located there.. For example, behind the signs of shops or on the balconies of houses.